# Fast way to update integer indexed slice in numpy

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I have a rather big numpy array, and I'm proceeding to clean up the data (this is pseudocode):

```
arr = np.ones(shape=(int(5E5), 1000), dtype=float)
to_zero = np.arange(500, 1000, 2) # Normally this is a function that finds 
                                  # columns be zeroed indexes are not continous
arr[:, to_zero] = 0
```

Problem is that `arr[:, to_zero] = 0` takes very long time. In this example it takes 4 sec. 
while `arr[:, :500]` takes 500ms.

Is there any way to make this faster?

Example numpy notebooks for [numpy 1.8.1](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/jbzdak/575e3dd36598a9869001/raw/54b4cac7d8e15d3e10ae1d325b8e05c198501093/gistfile1.txt) and [numpy 1.9 beta](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/jbzdak/575e3dd36598a9869001/raw/d052d04adcc81c5f7a6a77087385bf9c71efcaef/gistfile2.txt) (see timing results).

As @Jaime pointed using newer numpy is would be a good shot in the long term.

Comment: What numpy version are you using? The whole indexing system was rewritten for numpy 1.9, which has now a beta version out. I am using a 32bit Python, and can thus not reproduce your exact size, but it looks like it would run 4x faster without changing anything. You really don't want to use a for loop instead of fancy indexing, as numpy is eventually going to catch up on you, probably already did.

Comment: @Jaime I'm using ``1.8.1`` but I have installed numpy 1.9 beta (well actually ``master`` branch) results are better, but still not enough. I to suspect that this is a some performance issue in numpy fancy indexing. Do you think that it is worth submitting as an issue for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From numpy's internal storage point of view it is very fast to reset a large chunk of contiguous memory. With your example the problem is that you are jumping around the memory like a mad rabbit, as you are zeroing columns.

I tried turning your array the other way round, and then the speed increases almost by a factor of 3. I get 4.08 s for your version and 1.57 s for a transposed version. So, that at least is a good optimisation, if you can do it otherwise.

There may be something fishy in numpy with this indexing, because actually doing:

```
for c in to_zero:
    arr[:, c] = 0
```

is faster than using the list notation.

So, I ran a few different alternatives:

```
to_zero = numpy.arange(0, 500, 2)

# 1. table in the original orientation
arr = numpy.ones((500000, 1000), dtype='float')

# 1.1. basic case: 4.08 s
arr[:, to_zero] = 0

# 1.2. a bit different notation: 234 ms 
arr[:, 0:500:2] = 0

# 1.3. for loop: 2.75 s
for c in to_zero:
    arr[:, c] = 0

# 2. transposed table
arr = numpy.ones((1000, 500000), dtype='float')

# 2.1. basic case: 1.47 s
arr[to_zero,:] = 0

# 2.2. a bit different notation: 105 ms 
arr[0:500:2,:] = 0

# 2.3. for loop: 112 ms
for r in to_zero:
    arr[r, :] = 0
```

These have been timed with IPython %timeit, so the results may vary a bit across one run to another, but there seems to be a pattern. Transpose your table and use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do the way the data is allocated in memory.

But to solve your problem read the rows as columns and the columns as rows:

```
arr = np.ones(shape=(1000, int(5E5)), dtype=float)
to_zero = np.arange(500, 1000, 2) # Normally this is a function that finds 
                              # columns be zeroed indexes are not continous
arr[to_zero, :] = 0
```